# Method that returns BinaryTree according to preorder traversal

Tags: java, binary-tree, preorder

The problem I have is to write a method with the signature

```
public static BinaryTree generate(BinaryTree root)
```

(it's possible to add other parameters)

This method has to return a `BinaryTree` like given as parameter (same size and so on), it is needed only to change values in its nodes. Each node of the resulting tree has to have a value equal to the position the equivalent node was processed when we use preorder traversal on `root`. We start counting with 1.

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public int value;
    public BinaryTree left;
    public BinaryTree right;

    public BinaryTree(int value, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

I tried the below, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
public static BinaryTree preOrder(BinaryTree root, int num)
{
    //We ALWAYS give 1 as num value!!
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    root.value = num;       
    preOrder(root.left, ++num);         
    preOrder(root.right, ++num);

    return root;
}
```

For example, if we have a BinaryTree:

```
             3
         /      \
       2           1
    /     \
  1         0
```

(It doesn't matter what values there are in the nodes!)

Our method has to return this tree:

```
             1
         /      \
       2           5
    /     \
  3         4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do this with a recursive method. To assign node values, it is easiest to use a static counter that is accessible at all levels of recursion. The procedure is simple: every time you visit a node in the input tree, create a corresponding node in the output tree with a value set to the static counter, and then increment the counter before recursing on the left and right subtrees (if present).

By using a static variable instead of passing an `int` an argument (like you have in your current code), the increments done at deeper levels of recursion will be seen when the recursion returns.

If you don't want to use a static counter (or if it's against the rules), use an `int[1]` array that can be used to return as well as pass an `int` value.

If this is not clear, I can try elaborating more, but I'm not posting code because this sounds like a school assignment.

**EDIT** Since it's not a school assignment, here's code that does what you want:

```
public class BinaryTree {
    public int value;
    public BinaryTree left;
    public BinaryTree right;

    public BinaryTree(int value, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public static BinaryTree generate(BinaryTree root) {
        // allocate a counter and delegate to the recursive method
        int[] counter = {1};
        return generate(root, counter);
    }

    /**
     * Recursive method to generate a copy of a binary tree
     * with values indicating the preorder traversal order.
     *
     * @param root
     *        the root of the tree to copy
     * @param counter
     *        an array containing the traversal order counter as its
     *        first element. On entry, it should contain the value to
     *        use for the root of the generated (sub)tree. On return,
     *        it will contain one more than the last value used.
     */
    private static BinaryTree generate(BinaryTree root, int[] counter) {
        // recursion base case
        if (root == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // capture current value and increment the counter
        int value = counter[0];
        ++counter[0];

        // generate left subtree - this will change the counter unless
        // the left subtree is null
        BinaryTree left = generate(root.left, counter);

        // generate right subtree - may change the counter
        BinaryTree right = generate(root.right, counter);

        // Complete the copy by generating the root node;
        // return the result
        return new BinaryTree(value, left, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Its not really a school assignment, I just want to solve this problem by my own but probably Im not smart enough. Can you explain me please what is static counter? And what does it mean int[1] array that can be used to return?

Answer (score 0):

For the example tree does your code return something like this:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
 /  \
3    4
```

If so you're on the right track and probably understand using recursion to visit nodes in pre-order but you may have forgotten that int is a value type! I think... my java is rusty. Anyway if you can pass the int by reference and the problem is what I think it is you should be good. From a quick google search it looks like easy ways to make a "mutable int" is to wrap it in a single cell like Ted Hopp suggested (int[1]) or you can use MutableInt (full path in answer: [Java : Best way to pass int by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326112/java-best-way-to-pass-int-by-reference)).