# testcase not working properly. Issue setting two numbers equal to each other

Tags: java, testcase

I'm working on a test case and I'm having trouble. I'm having a hard time with getting my test cases to work. Here is the code:

```
    public class Appointment extends Actor
    {
        int hour;
        String description;

        public Appointment(int hour, String description)
        {
            super();
            this.hour = hour;
            this.description = description;
        }


        public void setHour(int newHour)
        {
            newHour = hour;
        }
    }
```

/////////

```
public class AppointmentTest extends TestCase
{

    private Appointment appointment;
    private int hour;
    private String description;
    private String newDescription;
    private int newHour;

    public AppointmentTest()
    {

    }


    public void setUp()
    {
        appointment = new Appointment(hour, description);
        this.hour = hour;
        this.description = description;
        hour = 7;
        description = "";
        newHour = 1;
        newDescription = "hello";
    }

    public void testSetHour()
    {
        appointment.setHour(1);
        assertEquals(newHour, hour);
    }
}
```

The issue is when I run my testcase it says that newhour is 7 ad hour is still 1. Does anyone know why?

Comment: There is no code that changes either `hour` or `newHour`... Are you sure you've posted all related code? (See [MCVE] for guidance)

Comment: I mean I can post all my code. But thats all the code that I think is relevant to the problem. Would it help if I just post everything.

Comment: If that the case you may want to read something about Java... Looks like you assume that values are passed by reference - check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326112/java-best-way-to-pass-int-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple mistakes in your posted code -

1.

```
public void setHour(int newHour)
{
    newHour = hour;
}
```

There's no instance variable called `newHour` in class Appointment. 
Even if it is getting inherited from class `Actor` you're not using `this.newHour` to set it hence your logic seems questionable here.

2.

```
public void setUp()
{
    appointment = new Appointment(hour, description);
    this.hour = hour;
    this.description = description;
    hour = 7; //this statement is overriding your this.hour = hour statement. what is the point?
    description = ""; //this statement is overriding your this.description = description statement. what is the point?
    newHour = 1;
    newDescription = "hello";
}
```

3.

```
public void testSetHour()
{
    appointment.setHour(1); // this statement doesn't make any difference for next assertEquals statement. It changes instance variable hour, not the local variable.
    assertEquals(newHour, hour);
}
```

At the time of calling `assertEquals` `newHour` is 1 and `hour` is 7.
So,

> The issue is when I run my testcase it says that newhour is 7 ad hour
>   is still 1

doesn't hold true.

Comment: glad it works. you can always accept the answer and upvote :P